# I need a method or setter how to override a String

Tags: javascript, string

??? This is my ask.
??? is. I need this method or setter.
I find ".valueOf()" but this is only getter.

```
var t = "Hello";
t.??? = "Bye";
console.log(t);
```

And t return "Bye"

OR

```
// this = "Bye"; // Is not working.
String.prototype.bye = function(){ this.??? = "Bye"; } 

var t = "Hello";
t.bye();
console.log(t)
```

And t return "Bye"

OR

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "px", {
    get: function(){ return parseInt(this); }, // This is OK
    set: function(a){ this.??? = a + " px"; } // This is problem
});
```

I try create something like this.
But it's not important I will solve it differently.

```
// This is OK
return document.querySelector("*").style.height.px;
// This is problem // I know it can't work like this.
document.querySelector("*").style.height.px = 10;
// I know.  This is the only solution. Create new get/set.
document.querySelector("*").style.heightPX = 10;
```

Comment: What is `???` ?

Comment: ??? is. I need this  method or set. I find ".valueOf()" but this is only getter.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t really get your question but if you want to overwrite string in variable simply do this

```
let word = 'car'; //initialize string in variable
word = 'apple'; //overwrite variable with new string
```

Comment: `let` not `Let` and `'` not `‘`

Comment: I was answering on the phone so that’s why I used ‘ and autocorrect starts first word with capital..

Comment: Oh I already revoked my downvote anyway

Comment: No problem, my bad, already fixed that :)

Comment: I need use string method or set !

Answer (score -1):

im pretty sure you mean this:

```
var t = "Hello"
myFunction(); //returns Hello
t = "Bye"
myFunction(); //returns Bye

async function myFunction(){
await console.log(t)
}
```